# JAVA How to copy over files from many external sources to the same Target?

Tags: java, file, path, copy, transfer

I am trying to copy over files from folders in different computers to the same local target folder.

```
/*Example there are 3 network folders mapped.
A: 192.168.10.1\folderA
B: 192.168.10.2\folderB
E: 192.168.10.3\folderC
*/

//Getting the image files from their folders respectively
//(E.g. 1.png, 2.png, 3.png)
String source1 = "A:/1.png";
String target1 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1.png"
String source2 = "B:/2.png";
String target2 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\2.png"
String source3 = "E:/3.png";
String target3 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\3.png"

try{
    Files.copy(Paths.get(source1), Paths.get(target1),
                  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.copy(Paths.get(source2), Paths.get(target2),
                  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.copy(Paths.get(source3), Paths.get(target2),
                  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}catch(IOException e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```

So source1 has been successfully copied over, but not 2 and 3, why is that so?

Comment: Note that your third copy should probably use `target3`, not `target2`  .

Comment: yup got it! typo... but still.. same thing though... only 1st one can be copied over

Comment: Do you get any exception or error for 2 and 3?

Comment: no exception at all... program still runs smoothly... but 2.png and 3.png are still not copied over.

Comment: `Files.copy()` returns number of bytes written. Is the value non zero for 2 and 3?